# Task Runner Explorer couldn't find webpack.config.js in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, webpack, task-runner-explorer

[image]

Task Runner Explorer couldn't load my webpack.config.js file even though I've  included in my project.

I tried moving $(PATH) to the first place in (Options -> External Web Tools) but it's still the same. Already got my webpack installed in npm.

Answer (score 0):

Just click refresh button on top-left of the Task Runner Explorer window, it worked for me. It should appear all the runner settings (Run, Profile, Serve, Watch) assuming that you have included webpack.config.js in the root folder of the project.